# Why does `rm -i kk kk*` complain about a missing kk?

Tags: shell, wildcard

Well i want to understand how rm command works,

What i tried:

```
touch kk kk.999 (so it creates 2 blank files the kk and the kk.999)
rm -i kk kk* (then i tried this command so it deletes kk and then try to delete all the files starting with kk but before it deletes kk.999 an error occurs)
```

My thoughts:

It deletes 'kk' and then i think linux try to delete kk* ('kk' and 'kk.999') but the only kk file left is kk.999 (because 'kk' is already deleted) so why it says that 'kk' didnt found? Whoever has linux please try the above commands and explain me what is happening... i cant understand.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: The shell expands the command line wildcards before the command is executed. `rm -i kk kk*` is equivalent to writing, `rm -i kk kk kk.999`. The second `kk` probably causes `rm` to yell about the file not existing since it already removed it. Why not just write `rm -i kk*`?

Comment: Because i want to understand why the error occurs... ofc if i need to remove i would do rm kk* so thanks... put this as an answer to Accept it if you want.!!

Comment: `set -x` will show you precisely this: `+ rm -i kk kk kk.999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell expands the command line wildcards before the command is executed. `rm -i kk kk*` is equivalent to writing, `rm -i kk kk kk.999`. The second `kk` causes `rm` to yell about the file not existing since it already removed it when it saw the first instance on the command line. You can just write `rm -i kk*` to ensure the file names aren't repeated.